# Not able to delete or rename files

Tags: windows

Few months back I had installed Windows 8 on my computer and as a result a Windows.old backup directory was created. The directory has lots of files with very long names. For example:

`'C:\\Windows.old\\Users\\XYZ\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\WinStore_cw5n1h2txyewy\\A
C\\Microsoft\\Windows Store\\Cache\\0\\0-Namespace-https\u223a\u222f\u222fservic
es.apps.microsoft.com\u222fbrowse\u222f6.2.9200-1\u222f615\u222fen-US.hi-IN\u222
fc\u222fUS\u222fNamespace\u222fpc\u222f00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\u222
f00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.dat'`

Now I am not able to delete/move/rename these files. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah but I found one.

I just used a Linux Live USB Stick. Mounted Windows partition and deleted damn folders. For me it freed about 21GB of disk space.

I took this version http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/

Here is the how-to for creating Live USB Sticks under Windows:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

So have fun with your new free space. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I will try out the solution.